PyTorch DDP is not returning correct number of results
I currently have a machine with four GPUs that I want to test out the following script with:
import os
import torch
import torch.distributed as dist
from torch.nn.parallel import DistributedDataParallel as DDP
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel
from torch.multiprocessing import Process
import numpy as np


def setup(rank, world_size):
    os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = 'localhost'
    os.environ['MASTER_PORT'] = '12355'
    dist.init_process_group("nccl", rank=rank, world_size=world_size)
    torch.cuda.set_device(rank)

def cleanup():
    dist.destroy_process_group()

def encode_text(rank, world_size, texts, model_name, return_dict):
    setup(rank, world_size)

    # Load tokenizer and model
    tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
    model = BertModel.from_pretrained(model_name).to(rank)
    model = DDP(model, device_ids=[rank])

    # Tokenize and encode the texts
    inputs = tokenizer(texts, return_tensors="pt", padding=True, truncation=True)
    inputs = {key: val.to(rank) for key, val in inputs.items()}

    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(**inputs)

    embeddings = outputs.last_hidden_state.mean(dim=1)

    # Gather all embeddings from all ranks
    gathered_embeddings = [torch.zeros_like(embeddings.cpu()) for _ in range(world_size)]
    dist.all_gather(gathered_embeddings, torch.tensor(embeddings))

    # Concatenate results
    gathered_embeddings = torch.cat(gathered_embeddings, dim=0).numpy()

    return_dict[rank] = gathered_embeddings
    cleanup()

def run_distributed_inference(texts, model_name):
    world_size = torch.cuda.device_count()
    processes = []
    manager = torch.multiprocessing.Manager()
    return_dict = manager.dict()

    for rank in range(world_size):
        p = Process(target=encode_text, args=(rank, world_size, texts, model_name, return_dict))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    # Combine results from all processes
    encoded_texts = np.concatenate([return_dict[rank] for rank in range(world_size)], axis=0)
    return encoded_texts

if __name__ == "__main__":
    texts = ["This is a test sentence.", "Here is another sentence.", "More text data to encode."]
    model_name = 'bert-base-uncased'

    encoded_texts = run_distributed_inference(texts, model_name)
    print("Encoded Texts:", encoded_texts)

The code is very simple, just take the three example texts and encoded them using a BERT model and DDP, then gather the results.
When I run the script I'm noticing that the shape of encoded_texts is (48, 768). Shouldn't it be (3, 768) since we have three sentences?
